# Authorize.net E-checks?

Tags: payment-processor, authorize.net

I need to be able to add the ability to do e-checks via Authorize.net. But it appears the only extension that was available for this says it shouldn't be used because it messed with a core CiviCRM file. So how are people doing this?

Edit: The previous answer is not an option. That page is from 2016 and the information is apparently from back when there was an extension. Without an extension connecting CiviCRM and Authorize.net, the solution there won't work. It's just an Authorize.net reseller. They don't provide extensions and such. So we're still looking for a solution. Or an estimate as to the cost to get the old extension working so that we can crowd fund it?

Answer (score 1):

The current [Authnet extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/authnet) supports e-checks and doesn't override core files, and hasn't since April 2019 (version 1.3).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer you want - but should help you get the answer you want.

Powerbase via PtP apparently has a solution for echeck via Authorize.net with Dharma Merchant Services

- https://network.progressivetech.org/node/1114
- https://dharmamerchantservices.com/nonprofit-rates/

They may have an answer for you.

Comment: Apparently this is not true. I contacted Dharma Merchant Services. They do nothing regarding CiviCRM - they're just an Authorize.net provider. They do not have anything to allow you to Authorize.net e-checks. I'm gathering that since the progressivetech,.org post is from 2016 that they were talking about back when there was an extension for CiviCRM.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is asking someone to write code to enhance the OmniPay extension to support E-Checks. Eileen maintains that.

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor

It could possibly already support it - but not sure.

Comment: There's already an Authorize.net e-check extension, but apparently it changes a core file, so it's not available to be used. If we can find out what it would take to just get that fixed, that would work. It needs to be Authorize.net since it's already in use.